# Debugging while developing Django apps

Tags: django, debugging

I'm aware of `pdb` built-in Python library for debugging Python programs and scripts. However, you can't really use it for debugging Django apps (I get errors when I try to use it in views.py). Are there any tools that I can use when Django's traceback isn't helpful ?

**EDIT:**

```
from .forms import TestCaseForm, TestCaseSuiteForm
from .models import TestCase, TestSuite
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.views.generic import FormView, ListView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import logout
import pdb

class ListAllTestSuites(ListView):
    template_name = 'list.html'
    context_object_name = 'username'

    def get_queryset(self):
        pdb.set_trace()          # <-- setting a trace here to diagnose the code below
        queryset = {'test_suites': TestSuite.objects.filter(user=self.request.user),
                'username': self.request.user}
        return queryset
```

Comment: https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Why can't you use pdb? *What* errors do you get?

Comment: Most good IDEs support a built-in debugger (which uses `pdb`) so you can just set breakpoints on the line of code where you want to halt execution. Pycharm, VSCode, Atom all have support for it. But there's no reason to get an error when using `pdb`, it should also work.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  I'd like to use pdb because I think it's a really nice tool. Well the error I get is `from .forms import TestCaseForm, TestCaseSuiteForm ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.forms'; '__main__' is not a package` which I think has something to do with the fact that I'm importing form classes and not a module.

Comment: @dirkgroten    I'm using Atom and downloaded debugger for Atom. Will give it a go. Really need to cut my debugging time in half.

Comment: pdb is __perfectly__ usable with Django (using the dev server of course), been doing this for years. Please edit your post to explain how you tried to use pdb in your view and what exact error you get (exact error message and full traceback, thx).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers   Please see the edit.

Comment: @Mark you forgot the exact error message and full traceback, and, more importantly, you forgot to explain **how you executed this code** to get this result. But anyway: from the error message, you're obviously trying to execute your view file as a plain python script (cf the reference to `__main__`). **This cannot work**.  What you have to do is restart your dev server and navigate to the url for this view. Then in your dev server's terminal you'll see the pdb prompt when the code execution reaches the breakpoint.

Comment: NB : another option (and most often a better one) is to run your code from the django shell (`./manage.py shell)` and then just use ̀`pdb.runcall()`, but for your specific case (debugging a view) you'd have to manually build a proper `HTTPRequest` to pass to the view, so it's easier to set a breakpoint / restart the dev server (if it didn't restart automatically) / navigate to the view / come back to the server's terminal.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers  Ohh ... I completely missed the fact the I'm supposed to run it while dev server is up and then navigate to the url in question then pdb will kick in. Well, we learn every day, don't we ? I suggest to put this as a suggested answer and I'll tick it for you because this is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot the exact error message and full traceback, and, more importantly, you forgot to explain how you executed this code to get this result...

But anyway: from the error message, you're obviously trying to execute your view file as a plain python script (cf the reference to `__main__`). **This cannot work**. A view is a module, not a script, and, moreover, any module dependending on Django needs some setup done to be imported (which is why we use the django shell - `./manage.py shell` - instead of the regular Python one).

For most case, you can just launch the django shell, import your module and use `pdb.runcall()` to execute some function / method under the debugger (no need to put a breakpoint then, but that's still possible).

Now views require a `HTTPRequest` as first argument which make them a bit more cumbersome to debug that way (well, there is `django.tests.RequestFactory` but still...), so your best bet here is to set your breakpoint, launch your devserver (or restart it - if it didn't already did, as it should), point your browser to the view's url, and then you should see the debugger's prompt in your devserver's terminal.